# How to elegantly check if the template type is derived from the specific base class in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a template class `Context`. I want to limit the user to use the specified type (`Stratege1` but not `Stratege2`) that is derived from a specific class `Base`.

```
class Base {
public: 
    virtual void run() = 0;
}; 
class Stratege1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void run() {
        printf("Stratege1 \n");
    }
}; 
class Stratege2 {
public:
    virtual void run() {
        printf("Stratege2 \n"); 
    }
}; 
template <typename T> class Context {
public:
    void run() { 
        t.run();
    }; 
private:
    T t;
};
```

It may be OK if the user want to invoke like this:

```
Context<Stratege1> context;
context.run();
```

However I don't expect the user use (to avoid unexpectedly potential run-time issues)

```
Context<Stratege2> context;
context.run();
```

Because `Stratege2` is not derived from `Base` class. Is there any elegant way to limit the concept during compilation?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Any class that is derived from class Base is accepted. Otherwise, it is rejected. It is not limited to types known. It is only a limitation to require the user implementing the template argument as specified (e.g., deriving from class Base only).

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, "");`

Comment: If the methods you want to use are virtual why not just write a simple non-template function that works on the base class pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::enable_if_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) (equivalent to `std::enable_if<B,T>::type`) and [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value> >
class Context {
public:
    void run() { 
        t.run();
    }; 
private:
    T t;
};
```

Comment: This is an elegant implementation but not easy to understand :-)

Comment: I dislike compilation error messages for failed substitution. For instance with your suggestion: `error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'`. Not that obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Since C++11, you can [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) something, this means get a nice compilation error when a compile-time check fails:

```
#include <type_traits> // is_base_of
template <typename T>
class Context {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value,
        "T must be a derived class of Base in Context<T>.");
public:
    void run() { 
        t.run();
    }; 
private:
    T t;
};
```

For instance:

```
Context<NotBase> c2;
```

> ```
> error: static_assert failed "T must be a derived class of Base in Context<T>."
>     -> static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value,
> note: in instantiation of template class 'Context<NotBase>' requested here
>     -> Context<NotBase> c2;
> ```

[Full program demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a81fcaec679f3e25)

Comment: This is another elegant implementation, thanks very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any elegant way to limit the concept during compilation?

Another possible solution is through partial specialization: the second template paramenter is `true` only if `T` is derived from base

```
template <typename T, bool = std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>
class Context;

template <typename T>
class Context<T, true>
 {
   private:
      T t;

   public:
      void run () { t.run(); }; 
 };
```

So you have

```
Context<Stratege1>  cs1;    // compile
// Context<Stratege2>  cs2; // compilation error
```

Unfortunately you can hijack `Context` explicating the second parameter

```
Context<Stratege2, true> cs2; // compile
```